# Solid circle spinning(rotating) with gradient border effect along the border rim of another solid circle

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Image: Outer Circle static with inner circle spin with gradient effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmPzB.png)

```css
.outer-circle{
  width:330px;
  height:330px;
  border:35px solid #001b33;
  position:absolute;
  top:0; bottom:0; left:0;right:0;
  margin:auto;
  border-radius:50%; 
}

.spinner {
 animation: rotate 4s linear infinite;
 background: cyan;
 border-radius: 50%;
 height: 280px;
 width: 280px;
 position: relative;
}

.spinner:before,
.spinner:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
}

.spinner:before {
 border-radius: 50%;
 background:
  linear-gradient(0deg,   hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 1) 50%, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.9) 100%)   0%   0%,
  linear-gradient(90deg,  hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.9)  0%, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.6) 100%) 100%   0%,
  linear-gradient(180deg, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.6)  0%, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.3) 100%) 100% 100%,
  linear-gradient(360deg, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.3)  0%, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0  ) 100%)   0% 100%
 ;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 50% 50%;
 top: -1px;
 bottom: -1px;
 left: -1px;
 right: -1px;
}

.spinner:after {
 background: white;
 border-radius: 50%;
 top: 3%;
 bottom: 3%;
 left: 3%;
 right: 3%;
}

@keyframes rotate {
 from { transform: rotate(0deg);   }
 to   { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-circle">
<div class="spinner"></div>
</div>
```

I need the output as shown in uploaded image. Here there are two problems:
1) Spinning circle not rotating along the rim of outer circle. I need it to be rotated exactly at the center of solid border of outer circle as shown in image. And the spinner border width also has to be little more. How can I achieve it?

2) Linear gradient effect color codes are not proper. I need the same color combination as in image. How can I achieve it with background: liner-gradient syntax?

Comment: This isn't a forum to have people do your work for you. The referenced answer addresses the essence of your question. Customizing it to your specific need is on you. If you have another specific question related to how to do that, then I would suggest opening another question with something more specific.

Comment: I don't need such suggestions from you. I clearly mentioned at the beginning that, I need clear code for the specific scenario with the same color combination. If you can provide the answer with the code, then do that, otherwise let others answer if they know the answer. As, I am not finding exact solution for my requirement, I posted here. Even I already saw that code with single spinning circle, what you have suggested here. As, I need it for two solid circles, that too, which rotates along the border rim of another circle. Don't simply make it as duplicate!!!!!!....It is not duplicate

Comment: No need to get worked up about it. Your example has two rings with one spinning inside of the other. The answer demonstrates how to do the fade which is the part you were missing. It seems that you have the pieces that you need to put together your solution. What do you feel that you are missing to put it together?

Comment: @bygrace Appreciate your help here. I modified my question and also code snippet. You came to track now. You are exactly right, I have the pieces that I need to put together to provide the solution. How can I provide the solution to the two problems I mentioned in my HTML and CSS code snippet.

Comment: The original was a duplicate so I can't give you a standard answer. You could ask as a new question but hope this helps: https://codepen.io/bygrace1986/pen/wmyarb

Comment: Thanks @bygrace. Your solution in codepen helped me a lot. Just I changed hsla effects as per my requirement. But, now only the problem is rotating animation is shaking in IE(checked in IE11). It is making spinner to shake a bit while spinning.

Comment: @bygrace Please, don't mind, I have created this IE browser issue mentioned as a separate question. There I have added your codepen solution code to illustrate the issue. I need some quick turn around on that, so I posted there with your code. I hope, you can understand.

Comment: Np, a new question is better than continuing here.

Comment: @bygrace One more thing here. I need the motion progress front part as somewhat half moon shaped or cylindrical bottom shaped as in the uploaded image. If you closely observe, that white inner spinner is bit half-moon shaped at the leading edge. How can we give such an effect to the spinner? Appreciate your help here. I created one pen here: https://codepen.io/sadashivjp/pen/oqqzwg                                                You are free to do any changes and post the solution here

Comment: I'm not sure that you can for this solution. You could open another question for it but I imagine that this will be much easier or at least straight-forward if you use an svg.