# How to make leading edge of CSS circle spinner half moon shaped

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Image: [Circular spinner rotating along the border rim of other solid circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5E9d.png)

Please visit: https://codepen.io/sadashivjp/pen/oqqzwg
I have create a UI codepen here. You are free to make any changes in this, and post the solution here.

The same code is as follows:

```css
.outer-circle{
  width:330px;
  height:330px;
  border:30px solid #001b33;
  position:absolute;
  top:0; bottom:0; left:0;right:0;
  margin:auto;
  border-radius:50%; 
}

.spinner {
 animation: rotate 5s linear infinite;
 border-radius: 50%;
 height: 360px;
 width: 360px;
 position: relative;
  left: -15px;
  top: -15px;
}

.spinner:before,
.spinner:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
}

.spinner:before {
 border-radius: 50%;
 background:
  linear-gradient(0deg,   hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0) 50%, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.1) 100%)   0%   0%,
  linear-gradient(90deg,  hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.1)  0%, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.5) 100%) 100%   0%,
  linear-gradient(180deg, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.5)  0%, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.60) 100%) 100% 100%,
  linear-gradient(360deg, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.60)  0%, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.70 ) 100%)   0% 100%
 ;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 50% 50%;
 top: -1px;
 bottom: -1px;
 left: -1px;
 right: -1px;
}

.spinner:after {
 background: black;
        border: 15px solid #001b33;
 border-radius: 50%;
 top: 3%;
 bottom: 3%;
 left: 3%;
 right: 3%;
}

@keyframes rotate {
 from { transform: rotate(0deg);   }
 to   { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-circle">
<div class="spinner"></div>
</div>
```

There are two problems in this code:
1) It is causing wobbling(shaking) effect of spinner circle in IE11 browser. But, works perfect in Google chrome browser.
2) As in attached image, need the similar effect of half moon shaped(cylindrical bottom shaped) at the leading edge at the front of the inner white spinner circle.

How to solve these two issues?
Modification of my existing code or providing solution with SVG or Canvas on any other would be fine.

Comment: so the same question as this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49555214/css-circle-rotate-animation-causing-wobblingshaking-in-ie11-browser

Comment: and this also : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49520226/solid-circle-spinningrotating-with-gradient-border-effect-along-the-border-rim

Comment: why you don't edit your previous Exact question to add more details ?

Comment: In that previous question, that comments adding was going on like that. So, instead of using comments there, I thought of creating a separate question here..

Answer (score 0):

Add a div inside your spinner.

```css
.outer-circle{
  width:330px;
  height:330px;
  border:30px solid #001b33;
  position:absolute;
  top:0; bottom:0; left:0;right:0;
  margin:auto;
  border-radius:50%; 
}

.spinner {
 animation: rotate 5s linear infinite;
 border-radius: 50%;
 height: 360px;
 width: 360px;
 position: relative;
  left: -15px;
  top: -15px;
}

.spinner:before,
.spinner:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
}

.spinner:before {
 border-radius: 50%;
 background:
  linear-gradient(0deg,   hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0) 50%, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.1) 100%)   0%   0%,
  linear-gradient(90deg,  hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.1)  0%, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.5) 100%) 100%   0%,
  linear-gradient(180deg, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.5)  0%, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.60) 100%) 100% 100%,
  linear-gradient(360deg, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.60)  0%, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.70 ) 100%)   0% 100%
 ;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 50% 50%;
 top: -1px;
 bottom: -1px;
 left: -1px;
 right: -1px;
}

.spinner:after {
 background: black;
        border: 15px solid #001b33;
 border-radius: 50%;
 top: 3%;
 bottom: 3%;
 left: 3%;
 right: 3%;
}

@keyframes rotate {
 from { transform: rotate(0deg);   }
 to   { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
.circle{
        background: #b1bac1;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 177px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 50% 50%;

}
```

```html
<div class="outer-circle">
  <div class="spinner">
      <div class="circle">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As I already mentioned in my post, I observe wobbling(shaking) of inner spinner circle in IE 11(Edge) browser. Not getting any solution to fix it. If you closely observe the spinner rotation, then only, you will be able to see that wobbling effect. Could you suggest any fix for that?

Comment: I forgot, Thanks for your solution. Need some suggestion to fix the browser specific issue that I mentioned, which is happening in IE11(Edge) browser

Answer (score 0):

```css
.outer-circle{
  width:330px;
  height:330px;
  border:30px solid #001b33;
  position:absolute;
  top:0; bottom:0; left:0;right:0;
  margin:auto;
  border-radius:50%; 
}

.spinner {
 animation: rotate 5s linear infinite;
 border-radius: 50%;
 height: 360px;
 width: 360px;
 position: relative;
  left: -15px;
  top: -15px;
}

.spinner:before,.spinner:after,
.outer-circle:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
}

.spinner:before {
 border-radius: 50%;
 background:
  linear-gradient(0deg,   hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0) 50%, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.1) 100%)   0%   0%,
  linear-gradient(90deg,  hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.1)  0%, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.5) 100%) 100%   0%,
  linear-gradient(180deg, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.5)  0%, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.60) 100%) 100% 100%,
  linear-gradient(360deg, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.60)  0%, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.70 ) 100%)   0% 100%
 ;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 50% 50%;
 top: -1px;
 bottom: -1px;
 left: -1px;
 right: -1px;
}

.spinner:after{
    background: #afb7bf;
    height: 15px; width:15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 175px;
    left: -1px;
    right: -100px;
    bottom: 0px;
}

.outer-circle:after {
 background: black;
        border: 15px solid #001b33;
 border-radius: 50%;
 top: -1px;
 bottom: -1px;
 left: -1px;
 right: -1px;
}

@keyframes rotate {
 from { transform: rotate(0deg);   }
 to   { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-circle">
<div class="spinner"></div>
</div>
```

I hope this is the solution you are looking for!

Comment: Thanks for your solution. This was the solution, that I was expecting. Thank you

Comment: As I already mentioned in my post, I observe wobbling(shaking) of inner spinner circle in IE 11(Edge) browser. Not getting any solution to fix it. If you closely observe the spinner rotation, then only, you will be able to see that wobbling effect. Could you suggest any fix for that?